# Draw edges and paths in the background of nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is it possible to draw edges or paths in the background of nodes independently of whether they are constructed before or after the nodes are defined?

In the following example, the `\draw` instruction comes after the nodes are declared and so the path from `(foo)` to `(baz)` crosses the node `(bar)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=gray!30] (foo) at (0,0) { foo };
    \node [fill=gray!30] (bar) at (2,0) { bar };
    \node [fill=gray!30] (baz) at (4,0) { baz };

    \draw (foo) -- (baz);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is that the path crosses `(bar)` in the background, so the node is not crossed visually. Is this possible without changing the order of the instructions (in particular, without moving the creation of `(bar)` below the `\draw` instruction)?

Here is how the above example looks like:

[image: edge crossing the node in the foreground]

And here is the desired result:

[image: edge crossing the node in the background]

Comment: Maybe you can just use `\draw (foo) -- (bar) -- (baz);`?

Answer (score 97):

TikZ/PGF has a concept of layers. They are described in chapter 82 “Layered Graphics” in the (v2.10) manual and can be used to have later commands be drawn below the things before them. In your example, you could write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background layer
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}  % set the order of the layers (main is the standard layer)

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=gray!30] (foo) at (0,0) { foo };
    \node [fill=gray!30] (bar) at (2,0) { bar };
    \node [fill=gray!30] (baz) at (4,0) { baz };

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}    % select the background layer
        \draw (foo) -- (baz);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Actually, the `backgrounds` library (see chapter 25 in v2.10) already defines a background layer and a key that has to be used on a `scope` to select the layer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=gray!30] (foo) at (0,0) { foo };
    \node [fill=gray!30] (bar) at (2,0) { bar };
    \node [fill=gray!30] (baz) at (4,0) { baz };

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw (foo) -- (baz);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The two solutions compile to the same code (except that the `backgrounds` library calls the layer `background`).)

Comment: I've used layers before but I wonder if it's possible to achieve what I want without drawing the path in a scope on the background layer. Are there any TikZ keys to define the layer per path/node or anything similar?

Comment: @Jannis: None that I know.

Comment: I talked to Till and soon edges might be drawn in the background of nodes by default, at least inside the new `\graphs{}` syntax that will be part of the next release.

Comment: There are situations where the two solutions aren't equivalent. For example, in case the background picture needs to refer to the `current bounding box` node, only the method with the `backgrounds` library will give the expected output.

Comment: In this solution, filling does the job of covering the line on the background layer.  If I need `(bar)` to have a transparent background, the part of the line underneath it is visible.  Is there any workaround simpler than something like `\draw (foo.east) -- (bar.west) (bar.east) -- (baz.west) ;`?