# Node transparent background

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have a very specific problem that repeats several times.  On picture I have a line and above line I have an arrow with a node.  Because of the line, node is not visible enough (picture left).  What I want to do is to make line more transparent.  I tried fill opacity, which is good in a way it makes line grey, but it also makes grey text as well as arrow (picture right).

Is there a way to make only line grey?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw[ultra thick,->] (2,2) -- (0.1,1) node[below left=-3pt,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\Phi_{x+\Delta x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw[ultra thick,->] (2,2) -- (0.1,1) node[rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,below left=-3pt,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\Phi_{x+\Delta x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** In recently deleted response, I've learned that `text opacity=1` solves the problem in a way it makes text black, but I still don't know how to prevent arrow to become grey.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the idea of `layers`, as demonstrated in [Draw edges and paths in the background of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18200/draw-edges-and-paths-in-the-background-of-nodes-in-tikz), for example, combined with the `text opacity` key.

[image: screenshot]

The idea is to draw your vertical line and node in the back ground, and then the arrow on top.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background layer
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}  % set the order of the layers (main is the standard layer)

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
    \draw[ultra thick,->] (2,2) -- (0.1,1) node[below left=-3pt,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\Phi_{x+\Delta x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}    % select the background layer
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
        \node[rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,fill=white,text opacity=1,fill opacity=0.5,below left=-3pt,inner sep=0.5pt] at (0.1,1)  {$\Phi_{x+\Delta x}$};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \draw[ultra thick,->] (2,2) -- (0.1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is still problem with the fact I don't want arrow to get grey